# passing variables in form_open() in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Good day all. I'm new to codeigniter and I'm trying to pass a variable from one `view` page to another. But I get error and after a lot of tries still couldn't figure it out.

This is the `Model` code:

```
function get_post($postID){
    $this->db->select()->from('khanposts')->where(array('post_id'=>$postID))->order_by('fullname', 'desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

function update_post($postID, $data)
{
    $this->where('post_id', $postID);
    $this->db->update('khanposts', $data);
}
```

This is the `Controller` code:

```
function editpost($postID)
{
    $data['success']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $data_post=array(
            'fullname'=>$_POST['fullname'],
            'dob'=>$_POST['dob'],
            'blood'=>$_POST['blood'],
            'village'=>$_POST['village'],
            'occupation'=>$_POST['occupation'],
            'company'=>$_POST['company'],
            'email'=>$_POST['email'],
            'contact'=>$_POST['contact'],
            'password'=>$_POST['pass'],
            'marry'=>$_POST['marry']);
        $this->khanpost->update_post($postID, $data);
        $data['success']=1;
    }
    $data['post']=$this->khanpost->get_post($postID);
    $this->load->view('edit_post', $data);
}
```

This is the code of `View` page which passes the value to `edit_post` view page:

```
foreach ($posts as $row){
<tr><td><a href="' .base_url(). 'khanposts/editpost/' .$row['post_id']. '" target="_blank"><i>Edit</i></a></td></tr>';
}
```

This is code of `edit_post` view page where it must get the value of `$row['post_id']`:

```
echo form_open(base_url().'khanposts/editpost/'.$row['post_id']);
echo '<b>Full Name: </b>';
$data_form=array('name'=>'fullname', 'size'=>30, 'id'=>'fullname', 'class'=>'inputstyle', 'value'=>$row['fullname'] );
echo form_input($data_form);
```

How do I assign the passsed variable(`$row['post_id']`) in `form_open()`? Any solution will be really helpful. Tnx.

Comment: you can use `form_open(base_url().'khanposts/editpost/?id='.$row['post_id'])` and in controller check for `$this->input->get('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As far as I understand the problem;*

Pass `PostID` to view in `editpost` function:

```
function editpost($postID)
{
   ...
   $data['postID'] = $postID;
}
```

Get it in `view` page like:

```
echo form_open(base_url('khanposts/editpost/'.$postID));
```

You should load `form` helper:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

And your `data_form` input:

```
$data_form = array('name'=>'fullname', 'size'=>30, 'id'=>'fullname', 'class'=>'inputstyle', 'value' => $post['fullname']);
```

You should use `row_array` instead of `result_array`, because of you get single post.

```
function get_post($postID)
{
    $this->db->select()->from('khanposts')->where(array('post_id'=>$postID))->order_by('fullname', 'desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: You write `$data['postID'] = $postID;` before the `$this->load->view``line, right?

Comment: Did you look `form action url`, is it empty? And try this variable in view page `echo form_open(base_url('khanposts/editpost/'.$post['post_id']));`

Comment: form action url is showing exactly what i wanted. It's passing the exact id like this:
`http://localhost/codeigniter/khanposts/editpost/5`

It's just the assigning problem. I both tried:
`echo form_open(base_url().'khanposts/editpost/'.$post['post_id']);`
and
`echo form_open(base_url('khanposts/editpost/'.$post['post_id']));`

Still I get this error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in I:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeigniter\application\views\edit_post.php on line 41`

Comment: @SinOscuras And you should load `form` helper. Updated answer

Comment: just put form in helper to your autoload.php

Comment: O M G...........such a silly mistake. I'm so noob at CodeIgniter. Tnx a lot bro. But then again how do I assign the values in
`$data_form=array('name'=>'fullname', 'size'=>30, 'id'=>'fullname', 'class'=>'inputstyle', 'value'=>???;`

Comment: @SinOscuras You're using `$row` variable. It is wrong. You passed with `$data['post']`. Use `$post` var instead of `$row` just like `'value' => $post['fullname']`

Comment: I did but its showing this error:
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: fullname

Filename: views/edit_post.php

Line Number: 43`

Comment: @SinOscuras Hmm.. Could you dump it in view page? `var_dump($post);` you will see..

Comment: I got these:
`array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["post_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["fullname"]=> string(14) " Humayun Kabir" ["dob"]=> string(11) "26 Nov 1960" ["blood"]=> string(2) "B+" ["village"]=> string(8) "Chandpur" ["marry"]=> string(6) "single" ["occupation"]=> string(8) "Employee" ["company"]=> string(27) "National Leather Enterprise" ["email"]=> string(21) "sir_humayun@gmail.com" ["contact"]=> string(10) "1676165367" ["password"]=> string(7) "123456" } }`

Comment: @SinOscuras Answer is updated. You should use row_array instead of result_array, because of you get single post.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Tnx a lot bro. TnQ for ur kind patience!